# CSS clear float with :after element not working

Tags: css, css-float, clearfix

I can't seem to get this right.
It's quite simple, clear the float after the h4 element (widget-title), so that the text box aligns left on a new line.

The HTML cannot be changed.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j29ubvjw/

```
.widget-wrap {
    padding:15px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}

.widget-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin:-15px 0 15px -15px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 15px;
    float:left;
}

.widget-title:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}


<div class="widget-wrap">
    <h4 class="widget-title">My Title</h4>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `::after` pseudo-element doesn't create content *after* the element itself, but appends a pseudo-child-element into the element.

In other words, by using `.widget-title::after`, a pseudo-element is appended after the contents of the elements matching `.widget-title` selector.

```
<h4 class="widget-title">
    ::before <!--appended pseudo-element -->
    My Title
    ::after  <!--appended pseudo-element -->
</h4>
```

---

In order to clear the floats after the heading, you could select the next adjacent sibling element and set `clear: both;` declaration to it:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/j29ubvjw/1/)**

```css
.widget-title + * { clear: both; }
```

Or in this case:

```css
.widget-title + div { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Glad to see you @Hashem, :)

Comment: Thanks @HashemQolami! send you request.